# Recreate search api tables

Tags: search

When use search_api, module automatic create more table:
search_api_db_article_title,search_api_db_article_body,...
But I accidentally lost these tables ==> search_api can't index. How to get back to the table?
I run cron, updatedb but nothing happen :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways are avaliable:

1. Recreate from nightly or hourly backup. This is preferred way to solve issues like yours.
2. Disable module, uninstall it, and then enable it again. Will be as good as new. To keep configuration:

   1. Export configuration search index to Features.
   2. Disable modules search_api, search_api_db,...
   3. Enable modules again => tables will be recreate.